# Define TYPO3 content element layouts for a specific list_type

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

In TYPO3 you can define custom Layouts to show up exclusively at 
*Appearance > Content Element Layout > Layout* 
for a specific CType like e.g. “gridelements_pi1”. How can i do this for specific list_type (where CType is “list”)?

code example:

```
TCEFORM {
  tt_content {     
    layout {            
      addItems {
        # layout items for all
      }

      types {
        # CType "gridelements_pi1"
        gridelements_pi1 {
          addItems {
            # layout items only for "gridelements"
          }
        }
        list {
          # is it possible to have
          # layout items only for list_type "XYZ" ?
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK it is not possible to limit this to a specific list_type.
CType = End of story (like in your example)

Possible solution: if this is your own extension, you can add your own unique CType instead of just calling it "list".

```
tt_content_defValues {
  CType = your_own_ctype
  list_type = extname_pluginname
}
```

Comment: yes, it seems that there is no built-in solution for the mentioned issue. but for now i will wait with accepting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Mikel already said: there are no more options in the typoscript structure to configure special plugins.

But it might be possible to use conditions which are possible in TSconfig to identify the plugin type in the current context.
I remember an installation where it was used, but I don't remember the exact configuration and whether this still works in newer TYPO3 versions. So unfortunately I have no working example or documentation for this case.

Answer (score 0):

In TYPO3 11+ you can do that with [itemsProcFunc](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/11.5/en-us/ColumnsConfig/CommonProperties/ItemsProcFunc.html). It allows more complex conditions for your layout options:

```php
// my_site_package/Classes/Tca/TtContentLayoutOptions.php

class TtContentLayoutOptions
{
    public function addOptions(array &$params): void
    {
        $ttContentEntry = $params['row'];
        $cType = $ttContentEntry['CType'];
        if (is_array($cType)) {
            $cType = $cType[0];
        }

        if ($cType == 'list' && $ttContentEntry['list_type'] == 'XYZ') {
            // Add layout options for list_type "XYZ" here:
            $params['items'][] = [
                'My example layout',
                '100'
            ];
        }

    }
}
```

Register your function:

```php
// my_site_package/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php:

$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['columns']['layout']['config']['itemsProcFunc'] =
    \MySitePackage\Tca\TtContentLayoutOptions::class .'->addOptions';
```

[Here](https://www.in2code.de/aktuelles/typo3-tt-contentlayout-und-frame-class-optionen-dynamisch-setzen/) is a tutorial for a more "configuration-like" approach. Unfortunately its in german, but it contains a full easy to understand code example.